# Can I map several physical interfaces to a single vmware vmnet interface?

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-server

I am using a rack mounted device that has 10 Ethernet ports built into it. For 8 of the ports, I would like to bind them to a single vwmare-server-2.0 virtual network interface, so that I can, in effect, use the ports as a hub for the external devices and internal virtual machines.

How can I bridge a single vmware vmnet# interface to several physical interfaces?

Comment: If you're using a dedicated piece of server hardware with multiple nics, you might find ESXi more appropriate than Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vmware Server depends on the host OS to set things up.  On Linux you should easily be able to setup bonding for all the interfaces.  For the best results  you will need a switch that supports this as well, and you will need to adjust your switch configuration to support using these 8 interfaces together.

Anyway once you setup bonding, you simply need to configure vmware to point at the bonded interface. (bondN)

See the related questions about bonding for more details:

- [Failover between 2 catalyst 2960s](https://serverfault.com/questions/78797/failover-between-2-catalyst-2960s)
- [Bonding Nics with Linux to get better performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/90078/bonding-nics-with-linux-to-get-better-performace)
- [Gigabit Teaming or Bonding](https://serverfault.com/questions/48213/gigabit-teaming-or-bonding)
- [NIC bonding with two uplinks](https://serverfault.com/questions/30549/nic-bonding-with-two-uplinks)
- [Bonding with 2 NIC's and 2 reserves?](https://serverfault.com/questions/107553/bonding-with-2-nics-and-2-reserves)

Comment: This seems correct, although I haven't tested it.